# Add custom tab in Sitemanager->Administrations->Users

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, kentico

I have a requirement that I need to add a extra tab in SiteManager->Administration->Users

This tab will have functionality of Users only but with more advanced filters, this is because HotFix/Version Upgrade of Kentico can update the default and code functionality of Kentico, so we don't want to update its basic functionality

So it's a risk if we change core Advanced Search functionality therefore we need to have a new page/webpart with our needed requirement.

[image]

Any help is appreciated, we have been looking on it from a while, didn't found any solution for the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version 7 I would do it this way:

1. Create your new search page by copying the existing one along with its underlying controls (to ensure upgrade won't break your changes)
2. Make your customizations
3. Navigate to CMS Site manager -> Development -> Modules -> Users -> Edit User -> User interface
4. Add UI Element e.g. "Advanced search"

   - set Target URL to your page
   - set Element is custom to true

Comment: Thanks Rocky :) You are KENTICO Genius :)